# Count function rather than count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am practicing for final exams coming up and in my database class we were thrown a question asking to count the rows of a table by creating a function and returning that number.

I know how to create functions but I am stuck on how to go about this.

Can you put `Count(*)` inside of the function with a `Select` statement and return it?

Comment: See the [SELECT...INTO... statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345)

Answer (score 3):

In this example, function accepts a parameter (table name) and returns number of rows it contains. `DBMS_ASSERT` is used to prevent possible SQL injection.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cnt (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     retval  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  7        'select count(*) from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name)
  8        INTO retval;
  9
 10     RETURN retval;
 11  END;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT f_cnt ('dual') FROM DUAL;

F_CNT('DUAL')
-------------
            1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TotalRecords 
RETURN number IS 
   total number; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT count(*) into total 
   FROM Your_table; 

   RETURN total; 
END;
```

Comment: Which will miserably fail for any table that contains more than 99 rows. And is restricted to `your_table` only.

Comment: @Littlefoot, Yes. I just write a sample code for the question. Thanks for the suggestion. Updated.

Comment: would I need to place a table parameter inside the arguments for the function? and then to call this method is it just CALL totalrecords(table_name);